# Accessing USer-Defined Type in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I've a user-defined type available in SQL Server under Master database (System Database). It pretty much works when I refer to the Master database (i.e. use master). However, I couldn't access the type from other databases. Do I've to add it to the other databases or I can refer to it even from where it is currently available? How can I make it accessible across all the available databases?

Comment: It has to exist in the other databases.

Comment: That's what I thought but it's not working for me. Do I need to make configurations? May be specifying the access level?

Comment: What does "not working for me" mean?

Comment: I can not access the User-Defined function across all other databases except within master

Comment: You need to show what you've done and what error message you're getting.

Comment: This is what am trying to do: select cast ('2/13/2003' as EthiopianDate).ToString() but it throws the error: Type EthiopianDate is not a defined system type. But if specify use master, it works just fine

Comment: And did you create EthopianDate as a type in the database you're working in?

Comment: Not really. Do I've to do that?

Comment: Yes, the type must exist in the database you're in. You can create it in model so it's created in new databases (and in tempdb, where it may be required as well).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the EthiopanDate type in each database. Code in db_x will not be able to see EthiopanDate in master, or vice-versa. This can also be an issue for temporary objects - to create a temp table with that data type in any of the columns, the type also needs to exist in tempdb. For this reason it canbe useful to either add the type to the model database (which will place it in tempdb on every startup, as well as every future database that is created directly on the server), or add an explicit create in a startup procedure.

That all said, I've written about why you might not want to do this anyway - it's mostly about what an incredible pain it is to change them:

- [Bad habits to kick : using alias types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types)